# Search for jobs with Cloud Talent Solution API in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-talent-solution

I cannot find any useful documentation whatsoever on how to use the Google Cloud Talent Solution API in Python to perform even a basic query. Right now I am trying:

```
from google.cloud import talent

credential_path = "creds_path/creds.json"
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credential_path

client = talent.JobServiceClient()
client.job_query(query="python")
```

This gives the result:

```
TypeError: search_jobs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query'
```

Removing `query` and trying other variables doesn't work. How do I use this API???